# (grep) Regex to match non-ASCII characters? FROM WINDOWS

Tags: unix, svn, utf-8, grep, non-ascii-characters

I'm developing a pre-commit hook to avoid committing files with non-ascii chars, it works as well from unix system, using the  below REGEX:

```
grep -P -n '[\x80-\xFF]' /tmp/app.txt
```

Now the issue that is giving me a lot of pain is that when i commit from windows, the result of the grep change, giving me a lot of char more than non ascii chars...

Does someone know how to fix this? I really try a lot of different things..

Comment: Can you invert the test and use something like `strings /tmp/app.txt`?

Comment: Sounds clever, can you go more in deep, it's not so clear to me what you meant..

Comment: Please tag it as windows

Comment: The basic problem is that the range doesn't work for UTF-8.  This has been discussed before.

Answer (score 0):

`strings -n 1 filename` will show the normal characters, but what if you only want to see the kind of file? `file filename` will show the kind of file but I am afraid it won't work for you.
You might try something like

```
cat /tmp/app.txt | tr -d "[:print:]\r\n" | wc -c
```

or avoiding the cat

```
tr -d "[:print:]\r\n" < /tmp/app.txt | wc -c
```